# Will the refresh tokens issue new access token if a compromised access token is sent to the server?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I have been reading about the concepts of access tokens and refresh tokens. I get the part of why refresh tokens might be useful to prevent re-logins and issuing short-lived access tokens to reduce the attack vector.

Consider the scenario where, If I log in, the backend server creates the access token and refresh token. The refresh token is kept with the server but the access token is with the client. Let's say in a cookie, and if the access token is stolen from the cookie and sent to the backend server that has the refresh token, will it issue a new token?

Can someone please help me understand why this is not a problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should *not* get a new access token / refresh token *unless* you have a valid refresh token.

So with an access token alone, you will keep access but eventually lose it.

Comment: Sorry, if the question wasn't clear. What I meant was what happens if I log in using OAuth, the backend server creates the access token and also the refresh token. The refresh token is kept with the server but the access token is with the client. Let's say in a cookie, and if the access token is stolen from the cookie and sent to the backend server that has the refresh token will it issue a new token?

Comment: @SrijanSrivastav no, it should not! if the access token is stolen, but the refresh token is not you will not get a new token. The only purpose of the refresh token is to get a new set of tokens. If that wasn't the case, then there's no real point to having two separate tokens

Comment: So the TL;DR is: the access token gives you access to some service, and the refresh token's only purpose is to give you a new set of tokens.

Comment: I get that part. How will the server distinguish that this a stolen access token and I must not issue a new one. That's what I'm struggling with how this is more secure than a long running access token if an attacker can just call an  API with the expired token and the server will just issue a new one using the refresh token it has saved.

Comment: If a client is completely comprimised, then a refresh token gives no additional protection on top an an access token. The idea for having 2 different tokens is that the refresh token can only be used once, and will only ever be sent to a presumably more secure server than an access token. So it's really less about the scope of what the token can do, but more about the more sensitive one has fewer chances of being stolen. aka 'security in depth'

Answer (score 0):

When an expired access token is produced to your Authorization Server, it will just not authenticate the request. It does not generate a refresh token.

When an access token expires, you use the refresh token to generate a new access token. Access tokens are short-lived, so they can be ferried around in slightly unsecure environment. Your refresh tokens are guarded in a safe environment and will not (need not) be ferried around like the access token.

Edit: You don't need an access token to get a new access token. All you need if a refresh token.

In Summary:

1. If you present your Authorization Server (AS) with an access token that is expired, your AS will say that the token is invalid.
2. If your access token expired and you want a new access token, you send **only** the refresh token to the AS and the AS will give you a new access token.
3. You do not need an (valid / expired) access token to generate a new access token. All you need is a refresh token.
4. A Refresh Token is kept in a secure environment, so it should not get compromised.
5. If an access token gets compromised, it can only be used until its validity. The attacker can not generate a new access token with the old access token.

Comment: Thanks, Rohan. I have made the question a little more clear.  Can you please take a look?

Comment: A refresh token is used to generate a new access token. You don't need an access token to generate a refresh token.

Comment: Yes, I understand but the point being how would the server know that this is a compromised access token, and I must not issue a new access token using the refresh token kept in the server.

Comment: The AS won't know this and the AS does not care if your access token that it generated before is compromised.